# Unwanted frequencies in sawtooth tone

Tags: acoustics, frequency, software, harmonics

Since 440 represents an A note, a 55 Hz tone also represents an A, since it is at 1/8 the frequency. However, when I generate this note in [Audacity](http://www.audacityteam.org/), I always get unwanted frequencies appearing as small peaks below the fundamental and all the harmonics.

Here's an example of a 55 Hz sawtooth wave generated at a 48000 Hz sample rate: 
[image]

You can clearly see those small peaks starting at 5 Hertz. What causes these unwanted frequencies to appear?

**Edit: I finally realised that these "ghost" frequencies are actually the result of** ***aliasing*** **because the sawtooth wave is not being band-limited (*id est:* not having its maximum frequency limited). The harmonics beyond the Nyquist frequency are being "mirrored down" to frequencies whose Hertz are multiples of the greatest common divisor between the fundamental frequency and the sample rate. In this case, the GCD between 55 and 48000 is 5, which explains the aliases appearing at multiples of 5 Hz. Another example would be the fact that a 43.75 Hz sawtooth wave generated non-bandlimited at 48000 Hz would produce aliases at multiples of 6.25 Hz.**

Comment: Just to be clear, you do know that a sawtooth wave is *not* a pure tone, right? Only sine waves are pure tones, so any other function, even if it's periodic at 55Hz, will necessarily have harmonic peaks at multiples of 55 Hz. That said, the sub-harmonics do look like an artifact, but it's hard to diagnose further than Sean E. Lake's observation that they're likely to be due to the envelope without additional information about exactly what it is you're doing.

Comment: Would [dsp.se], or possibly [electronics.se], be a better home for this question?

Comment: But notice all the peaks at 5, 10, 15, etc. Hertz.

Comment: Yes, precisely, that's what "sub-harmonics" refers to. But the question is unclear on what the role of the sawtooth wave is, as well as its harmonics. Why not re-run this with a sine wave, and cut out a source of noise and confusion?

Comment: A sine wave shows only 55 Hertz. None of those parasitic sub-harmonic and intra-harmonic(?) frequencies...

Comment: I'm using sawtooth. 55 Hertz frequency, 48K sample rate, 8 seconds long.

Comment: Can you post an image where the axis labels and tick labels are legible, please?

Comment: Got a new image with the grids.

Comment: Just a SWAG but 55 Hz (and harmonics) mixing with a 60 Hz (50 Hz) mains 'hum' (and harmonics) might produce 5 Hz (and harmonics).

Comment: This situation has nothing to do with mains noise

Comment: If your 'situation' is entirely within the digital domain, then why not state that?  I've noticed a certain 'laziness' on your part when it comes to providing sufficient context.  Is that by design?  What is you intention?

Comment: Actually, even if you think this is in the digital domain, @AlfredCentauri 's theory may have something to it. Because many such software packages produce some of their signals either from sampled instrument sounds or using linear predictive encoding of non digitally produced sounds or other means that can and does encode contamination into the digital model. Sibelius does this, for instance. How is the sawtooth produced? You need to describe the whole signal processing path that leads to what you have: you almost certainly have some kind of intermodulation happenning there. Piano synthesis ..

Comment: ... models will produce intermodulation as they try to digitally model the intermodulation arising from the real instrument (particularly through the nonlinear response of the metal frame).

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the fact that 48000 (sampling frequency) is not divisible by 55 (the frequency of the sawtooth wave)?

Comment: No, although a good guess, the sampling rate does not yield the sum and difference terms. Only nonlinear processes can do that. To get an idea of the effect you are postulating, work out the discrete Fourier transform of $\left\{e^{i, \omega\,k}\right\}_{k=0}^n$ and you'll see its a lone peak. If $\omega$ is harmonically related to the sampling frequency, the peak comprises a finite number of nonzero points. If not, then the peak spreads over all frequencies but it's still only one peak.

Comment: Converting "answer" by @Robert Logozar into a comment: "Thanks El Ectric to posting this question. I noticed the same artifacts when creating the SAW signal in Steinberg WaveLab 6. Without trying to offer the right answer now, I would like to invite the people interested to investigate the stated phenomenon further, perhaps even in a kind of scientific paper. (Of course, the good knowledge of the DSP is welcome). To contact me, please google my name or find my profile on ResearchGate. R.L."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your sampling rate is 48k at 55Hz, so each period is 872.73 samples. The size of your FFT is 65536. It fits 75.093 period of the signals. The algorithm takes 75 periods to plot the chart. This leaves 0.093 periods between consequitive FFT transforms. 0.093 periods at 55Hz correaponds to a frequency of 5.1Hz that matches the ghost frequency that you see within the margin of error.

This frequency or its harmonics are not present in the sound, but are a mathematical error created by the size of the FFT transform (2^16) not relating by a whole number to the number of samples in the period of the signal.

Furthermore, by the same logic, the 5.1Hz ghost creates a secondary artifact at 0.04Hz that you also see. Specifically, 5.1hz is 9,350.6 samples per period at 48k. The 65536 FFT size fits 7.0087 periods. 7 periods are displayed at about 5Hz and the 0.0087 period error at 5Hz creates a 0.04Hz ghost that you see on the left. At about -80dB, the values are small and are affected by the rounding and other errors, by the precision of the computer clock, and other factors, so the actual values that you see may slightly vary.

The calculation shows that the artifacts should diminish, if you reduce the generated frequency from 55Hz to approximately 54.93Hz. Alternatively you can increase the sampling frequency to 48.06k. However, you cannot change the FFT size just slightly, because it must be a power of 2.

Comment: Changing to 54.93 only increases the "ghastliness" of the frequencies though. I think it is because each period is not an integer number of samples (and thus the rounding) that results in these ghost frequencies? Whenever the sample rate is an integer multiple of the frequency of the tone, there are no "ghosts." But whenever the sample rate is not an integer multiple of the frequency, these ghosts reappear.

Comment: So I was pretty close. Essentially the same idea, only with the sample rate instead of the FFT size divisible by the frequency. I'm glad you have it figured :)

Comment: So it all comes down to "ghost frequencies will appear whenever (frequency)/(sample rate) is not a whole number"? But that "triangle" at the lower left of the spectrogram appears all the time.

Comment: @ElEctric I think we've established for sure that the ghost artifacts are created by the substandard signal processing in the software. A good FFT software would interpolate the signal first to a 32-bit floating point format, so all artifacts move down below the level of resolution. This one obviously just uses the samples without interpolation. There's nothing really you can do with a bad piece of software, but replace it with a better one. Fortunately there is no shortage of software tools today. You can get a different FFT program or just use a different workstation instead of Audacity.

Comment: It's not substandard signal processing. What I have come to conclude is that if the length of each period is not an integer number of samples, ghost frequencies will appear at every integer multiple of the GCF of the tone frequency and the sample rate at large FFT sizes. The only exceptions are "square-like" waveforms (anything followed by itself inverted and then the whole thing repeated, such as a square or triangle wave), where the ghosts appear at only odd harmonics of the GCF, and a sine wave (pure tone), where there are no ghosts regardless of the divisibility.

Comment: Re, "You cannot change the FFT size just slightly, because it must be a power of 2." So, don't use FFT. FFT is an algorithm for computing a discrete Fourier transform, and it happens to require a power-of-two number of samples, but it is not the only algorithm. There is [at least one other](http://www.fftw.org/), not quite as fast as FFT, but still fast enough to be practical, that works for any arbitrary number of samples.

Answer (score 4):

I can't be certain that this is generating your peaks, but any tone that starts and stops won't be 100% pure; a pure tone has no beginning and no end. Consider a tone that starts at $0$ at $t=0$, vibrates for time $\tau$, and then turns off. As an equation, that looks like this:
$$y(t) = \sin(2\pi f t)\, \Theta\left(\tau-t\right)\, \Theta(t),$$
where $\Theta(x)$ is the [Heaviside (unit step) function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function). If we integrate that against $\mathrm{e}^{i\omega t} (2\pi)^{-1/2}$, we get:
\begin{align}
\tilde{y}(\omega) & \equiv \int_{-\infty}^\infty \sin(2\pi f t)\, \Theta\left(\tau-t\right)\, \Theta(t) \frac{\mathrm{e}^{i\omega t}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \operatorname{d}t \\
&= \int_0^\tau \left(\frac{\mathrm{e}^{i2\pi f t}-\mathrm{e}^{-i2\pi f t}}{2i}\right)\frac{\mathrm{e}^{i\omega t}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \operatorname{d}t \\
& = \frac{1}{2i\sqrt{2\pi}}\left[\frac{\mathrm{e}^{i2\pi f t + i\omega t}}{i(2\pi f+\omega)} - \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-i2\pi f t + i\omega t}}{i(-2\pi f+\omega)}\right]_{t=0}^\tau \\
& = -\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}} \left[\frac{\mathrm{e}^{i[2\pi f  + \omega ]\tau}}{(2\pi f+\omega)} - \frac{\mathrm{e}^{i[-2\pi f  + \omega ]\tau}}{(-2\pi f+\omega)} - \frac{1}{(2\pi f+\omega)} + \frac{1}{(-2\pi f+\omega)}\right] 
\end{align}
If $ f\tau=N$ is an integer, then we can simplify the above to:
$$\tilde{y}(\omega) = \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}f}{\omega^2-(2\pi f)^2} \left(\mathrm{e}^{i\omega\tau} - 1\right).$$

Taking the absolute square to get something proportional to the power yields:
$$P \propto \tilde{y}^* \tilde{y}= \frac{(2\pi f)^2}{\pi (\omega^2 - (2\pi f)^2)^2} (1 - \cos(\tau\omega)).$$

To see if this is the dominant contributor to your unwanted harmonics, try producing a tone that lasts twice as long, and one that lasts half as long, and see how that affects their locations. You should also expect unwanted harmonics from sampling and digitization, though I don't know how to describe where they'll pop up.

Edit: I didn't notice you were talking about a sawtooth wave. As @EmilioPisanty noted, saw tooths are not sine waves. The saw tooth is responsible for the dominant harmonics on the right side of the graph. Drop those (to get a pure sine wave), and you get something that is plausibly of a squared [Lorentzian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution) form. Also, the unwanted harmonics don't start around $5\operatorname{Hz}$, notice the edge of a purple lobe off the end of the graph. I'd bet the first lobe is near $0 \operatorname{Hz}$, exactly as you'd expect if you didn't have an integer number of wavelengths in your wave-form. $0\operatorname{Hz}$ represents a net constant offset to the signal, and that sort of unbalancing is what happens when you don't spend an equal time above and below equilibrium.

Edit: Sparked by @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance's comment, I decided to code up my own tone generator. The sawtooth wave I generated using Golang, writing out to text, and importing to Audancity produces the same spectrum. Just like the Audacity generated spectrum, the $5\operatorname{Hz}$ peak vanishes when the "Size" parameter is reduced to 16384, or lower. What's going on here, I think, is there is additional windowing imposed by [how the spectrum is generated](http://ttmanual.audacityteam.org/o/man/plot_spectrum.html):

> Plot Spectrum take the audio in blocks of 'Size' samples, does the FFT, and averages all the blocks together.

The windowing from generating the spectrum seems primarily to affect a sort of noise floor, though, so this just disguises the peak. I don't know the details of what's going on, but there's a hint in comparing the square wave with "square wave, no aliasing". Judging by the zoomed in version, where ringing is apparent, the "no aliasing" wave is generated using a sum of sine waves, as opposed to the simple mathematical algorithm with sharp cutoffs.

Point being, this is probably a case of [aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing): square and sawtooth waves contain frequency information that is higher than the sampling rate can faithfully represent, producing the audio equivalent of a [Moire pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern) (i.e. a low frequency tone/beat frequency).

Comment: OP's sampling rate at 48 kHz looks to me like it's much too high for sampling artifacts to show up at that range, and this is the same digital computer feeding signal to itself, so there can't be any ADC artifacts. But, that said, maybe there's noise from the finite precision coming in, as an 'effective' ADC effect? If so, OP can probably diagnose that by using a higher bitrate.

Comment: Note that the peaks are all occurring at multiples of 5. Might it have to be due to the fact that 48000 is not divisible by 55?

Comment: @ElEctric How long was the sample used to generate the graph?

Comment: @Sean E. Lake: 8 Seconds.

Comment: @ElEctric did you try 4 seconds and 16 to see how that affected things?

Comment: Same thing. The spectrogram was unchanged

Comment: Using $\omega$ and $f$ in the same equation is *really* weird looking. I would recommend picking either angular or normal frequency and then distinguishing the source frequency and Fourier transform frequency with something like $\omega_\text{source}$ or using $\Omega$ and $\omega$.

Comment: @ElEctric Try playing with the sampling rate ("project rate" in the lower left hand corner), and the window size ("Size" in the spectrum plotting tool). You'll see that these are related to those, somehow. Likely a beat frequency among the signal, sampling rate, and analysis window size.

Comment: No audible beats here.

Comment: @ElEctric You realize that the tones you're worried about are more than $55\operatorname{dB}$ from the peak, right? That's more than 300,000 times quieter than the peak. What I mean by "beat frequency" is a difference between the frequencies inherent in these processes. See what happens when you set the sampling rate to $352,800\operatorname{Hz}$, for example. Were I you, I'd export the sound file then FFT it in Octave or Matlab to get a more accurate picture.

Comment: But that's the point of not setting such a high sample rate. It's to show how the effect is magnified at low (sample rate)/(freq) ratios.

Comment: I don't think this works as the whole explanation (although it is definitely a plausible line of reasoning to try for an explanation and your experimental suggestions are good ones): you're describing spectral leakage owing to windowing; usually this looks like broadening of peaks and what we see here is more like AM modulation of the sawtooth fundamental and higher harmonics. My guess here is that there may be intermodulation with something else: possibly the 50Hz or 60Hz line frequency. You'd get sum and difference terms at the 5Hz intervals as shown: then your analysis explains why these ..

Comment: ... sum and difference peaks are broad.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance Not a chance. This is a signal produced digitally, then analyzed digitally in the same software that generated it.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure of that (i.e. do you ken Audacity specifically)? Because many such software packages produce some of their signals either from sampled instrument sounds or using linear predictive encoding of non digitally produced sounds or other means that can and does encode contamination into the digital model. Sibelius does this, for instance. If you look at the vertical axis, these artefacts are very feint indeed.

Comment: A sawtooth tone does not start and stop. @Safesphere nailed the answer to this one though. When you compute a DFT of 65536 samples, you are analyzing a periodic function that yields an infinite number of repetitions of those exact 65536 samples.  But in this case, that is *not* the function that the OP wanted to analyze, because the function that the OP wanted to analyze does not fit exactly into that many samples. The function that the OP actually analyzed was _almost_ a 55Hz sawtooth, but with a little glitch in it once every 1.365 seconds.

Comment: P.S., The purpose of applying a _[window function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function)_ before computing a DFT is to try to reduce the visibility of those artifacts that are created when the signal either is not periodic or, contains frequencies that are not exact multiples of $sampleRate / windowSize$.

Answer (score 1):

the sawtooth waveform is rich in harmonic content and this would show up in the spectrum. note also that computer-generated waveforms are sometimes spectrally impure because of algorithmic errors and D-to-A conversion artifacts.

Comment: Note that OP is not complaining about the harmonic content (at 110 Hz, 165 Hz, etc), but instead about the sub-harmonic content that is not part of the expected sawtooth-wave signal. Similarly, this appears to be the audacity software feeding a digital signal directly to its own analyzer, so neither DAC nor ADC artifacts are directly applicable.